# how to call a legacy WCF SOAP from AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, wcf, soap, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am a very amateur coder, I am experimenting with Alexa Skills, I want to be able to use Amazon AWS to pass an XML message not JSON to an existing c# WCF service which expects a formatted XML message and responds with an XML.
how do I create a lambda to call a publicy accessible API that is NOT hosted by Amazon the WCF service I am calling is an established one that talks to a database and has all the methods and functions I need I just want to be able to use Amazon Alexa to talk to it via AWS.

having searched I have found examples of moving the API into AWS, but not where I want AWS to call my legacy API.
I have used StackOverflow for years to help, but have never asked a question, I am an amateur coder not a professional so any links or clear examples of how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated /sample code I can manipulate.
Alexa to AWS to XML to WCF to DB to WCF to XML to AWS to Alexa

this is not the actual task I am trying to do but an explanation of how I see the process working
Alexa ask "Cars available" if the Mercedes is available on 20 February 2018
this would invoke AWS
I need some code to create an XML and call my WCF and process the XML returned

I know the below are not fully formed XML requests merely to express my idea
example possible outbound XML from AWS to WCF SOAP
Mercedes
20 February 2018

example possible response

```
<Available>Yes</Available>
<Vehicle>Mercedes</Vehicle>
<BookingDate>20 February 2018</Booking Date>
```

another possible response

```
<Available>No</Available>
<Vehicle>Mercedes</Vehicle>
<BookingDate>20 February 2018</Booking Date>
```

AWS would process the returned XML
and pass an utterence back to ALexa

Alexa would say "Yes a Mercedes is available on 20 February 2018"

I just need some code to see how you can get AWS to create an XML request and call a WCF service with the XML and handle the XML response.

links code greatly appreciated.

Comment: my outbound request from AWS to my WCF would be something like <Vehicle>Mercedes</Vehicle>
<BookingDate>20 February 2018</Booking Date>

Comment: This link may be of use https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/12/serverless-soap-legacy-api-integration-java-aws-lambda-aws-api-gateway/